# React, Firebase: Access values of JSON and also get key value

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am beginner working with firebase, react. I am able to get the required data from firebase based on userEmail. But I am very confused in accessing the data.

```
firebase.database().ref('/users').orderByChild('email').equalTo(userEmail).on('value', data => {
        console.log('data: ', data);
    })
```

I get the following output:

```
data:  Object {
"-Lhdfgkjd6fn3AA-": Object {
        "email": "t5@gmail.com",
        "favQuote": "this is it",
        "firstName": "t5",
        "lastName": "l5",
    },
 }
```

Please help me how to access all values ("-Lhdfgkjd6fn3AA-" , firstname, lastname, email and favQuote) into variables like: data.firstName, data.lastName, data.key, etc   . Thank you.

Comment: You can get the value using: **data.-Lhdfgkjd6fn3AA-.email**

Comment: @NullPointer No, you can't. Use bracket notation instead.

Comment: @CertainPerformance-Ya.I missed thanks

Comment: `-Lhdfgkjd6fn3AA-` should be id which is unpredictable, and hence in his program I don't think he can pre guess the "key"

Comment: Can you please tell me how to access -Lhdfgkjd6fn3AA- from the above data?

Answer (score 2):

```js
let data = {
 "-Lhdfgkjd6fn3AA-": {
        "email": "t5@gmail.com",
        "favQuote": "this is it",
        "firstName": "t5",
        "lastName": "l5",
    },
 };
 
 console.log(Object.keys(data))//returning an array of keys, in this case ["-Lhdfgkjd6fn3AA-"]
 console.log(Object.keys(data)[0])
 console.log(Object.values(data))//returning an array of values of property
 console.log(Object.values(data)[0].email)
```

Do need to be careful that the above code with the hardcoded "0" as index because it assumed that your `data` object has only one key. If you have more key, you can't simply replace index either because property of object has no predictable sequence

Comment: I was not able to retrieve the values. This is what I got:
data:  Array [
21:23:58:   "node_",
21:23:58:   "ref_",
21:23:58:   "index_",
21:23:58: ]
21:23:58: dat1:  node_
21:23:58: dat2:  Array [
21:23:58:   ChildrenNode {
21:23:58:     "children_": SortedMap {
21:23:58:         "color": false,
.............
21:23:58:         "key": "-Lhdfgkjd6fn3AA-",
21:23:58:         "left": LLRBEmptyNode {},
21:23:58:         "right": LLRBEmptyNode {},

Comment: @kumar111: That is not the **data** that you've shared in the question

Comment: When I print data after async from firebase will give me the one that I posted in my question. But when I tried to print using Object.keys(data), then it prints entirely a different output. I am not sure why. 
data.key gives me users 
data gives me: data:  Object {
"-Lhdfgkjd6fn3AA-": Object {
        "email": "t5@gmail.com",
        "favQuote": "this is it",
        "firstName": "t5",
        "lastName": "l5",
    },
 }

but Object.keys(data) gives me : 
object data:  Array [
21:41:32:   "node_",
21:41:32:   "ref_",
21:41:32:   "index_",
21:41:32: ]

Comment: @kumar111: You've just said it yourself, `data.key` gave you the users data, so instead of just `Object.keys(data)`, change it to `Object.keys(data.key)`

Comment: data.key gives me "users" which is the like the table name of  all data. It doesn't give me list of users. 
Object.keys(data.key) gives me : 
Array ["0,"1","2","3","4"]

Comment: But you said `data.key` gave you **Object { "-Lhdfgkjd6fn3AA-": Object { "email": "t5@gmail.com", "favQuote": "this is it", "firstName": "t5", "lastName": "l5", }, }** ?

Comment: No. data.key gave me "users"  but data gave me that object notation which I posted in main question.

Comment: In that case, just refer to my answer

Comment: Anyway, I think it's better that you try to understand how `Object.keys`/`Object.values` work, then apply it to whatever object that you wished

Comment: Figured it. Using data.toJSON() worked. 
let data2 = data.toJSON()
console.log(Object.keys(data2)[0]) - gave me the key
 console.log(Object.values(data2)[0].email) - gave me email

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's really a JavaScript question. I had to figure this out too. ...this works.

```
var p;
var thisLine;
p = docu.data();
for (var k in p) {
    if (p.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
        if (isObject(p[k])) {
            thisLine = p[k];
            Object.keys(thisLine).forEach(function (key, index) {
                console.log(key, index);
            });
        }
    }
}

function isObject(obj) {
    return obj === Object(obj);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

So your first step is that you need to loop over the snapshot in your `on()` callback.

The second step is that you need to call `Snapshot.val()` to get the JSON data from the snapshot. From there you can get the individual properties.

```
firebase.database().ref('/users').orderByChild('email').equalTo(userEmail).on('value', snapshot => {
    snapshot.forEach(userSnapshot => {
        let data = userSnapshot.val();
        console.log('data: ', data);
        console.log(data.email, data.firstname);
    });
})
```