# Firebase realtime db query showing undefined?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have following data in my firebase console.

[Firebase updated console image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxP81.png)

Below is the json form of above image.

```
"Messages" : {
    "fYIM9pgpGdUpXtgrC3CavJyoN" : {
           "1FH4baB4LLeKhPjUqiGvj5T6DU" : {
              "chat": {// all chat here
               },
              "chattingid" : {
                    "chatid" : "1FH4baB4LLeKhPjUqiGvj5T6DU"
                }
            },
            "TCAv2NtQYdUXkF2COgZslsXARh" : {
                "chat": {//all chat here
                 },
                "chattingid" : {
                        "chatid" : "TCAv2NtQYdUXkF2COgZslsXARh"
                    }
                },
            }
            
            
}
```

I am using following query to get all chatid and getting undefined twice in my console.

```
firebase.database().ref("Messages/"+suid).orderByChild("chattingid").on("child_added", function(data){
       
    console.log("You are here to see "+ JSON.stringify(data.val().chatid));
        
})
```

How to get all chatid with firebase query. Is it possible? Thanks

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in the overflow menu (⠇) of [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: I haven't used firebase in a little while but I'm inclined to say that you should replace your `.orderByChild("chattingid")` with `.orderByChild("chattingid/chatid")` since **chattingid** is an object and you likely want to sort by the actual text that's within the _chatid_.    Also, welcome to SO!

Comment: @user999 following up on @raphael 's answer, the best thing to do when you're not sure why you're seeing what you're seeing is to just print out `data` and narrow it down from there.  If `data` provides you with an array, then great, you can work from there and console.log in iterative steps to get what you're aiming for.  If `data` is undefined then you know you have something up within your firebase query that needs to be addressed.

Comment: Hi @FrankvanPuffelen Json added.

Comment: Hi @nviens still same. Getting undefined twice

Comment: Good catch @nviens. The nested property indeed needs to be specified in the `orderByChild()` call. You might want to write that up as an answer, so we can upvote it. 

Comment: Hi @FrankvanPuffelen can you please guide how to get all chatid. Please check my updated console image and JSON is also added. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The data is returned as an array so you use forEach to get the chatid's

```
firebase.database().ref("Messages/" + suid).orderByChild("chattingid").on("child_added", data => {
            data.forEach(snapshot => {
                console.log("You are here to see " + snapshot.val().chatid);
            })
 })
```

Comment: Hi @raphael. Getting error No index defined for chattingid. please guide further how to index it in firebase console. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Posting my comments as an answer.  I haven't used firebase in a little while but I'm inclined to say that you should replace your `.orderByChild("chattingid")` with `.orderByChild("chattingid/chatid")` since chattingid is an object and you likely want to sort by the actual text that's within the chatid.

So I would recommend starting with something similar to the following:

```
firebase.database().ref("Messages/"+suid).orderByChild("chattingid/chatid").on("child_added", function(data){
    console.log("You are here to see ", data.val());
})
```

The best thing to do when you're not sure why you're seeing what you're seeing is to just print out data and narrow it down from there.

If data provides you with an array, then great, you can work from there and console.log in iterative steps `console.log(JSON.parse(data));` or `console.log(JSON.stringify(data));` to get what you're aiming for. If data is undefined then you know you have something up within your firebase query that needs to be addressed

**EDIT**

You could consider trying to do the following to get the chatids, since by your query you're fetching "Messages/fYIM9pgpGdUpXtgrC3CavJyoN" and the resulting value should be something similar to the following.

```
  "1FH4baB4LLeKhPjUqiGvj5T6DU" : {
   "chat":{// all chat here}
    "chattingid" : {
      "chatid" : "1FH4baB4LLeKhPjUqiGvj5T6DU"
    }
  },
  "TCAv2NtQYdUXkF2COgZslsXARh" : {
    "chat":{// all chat here}
    "chattingid" : {
      "chatid" : "TCAv2NtQYdUXkF2COgZslsXARh"
    }
  },
```

The keys match the chatids field, so you could probably do the following to get the ids (or specifically the keys from the json object that's returned which should match the chatids field).

```
firebase.database().ref("Messages/"+suid).orderByChild("chattingid/chatid").on("child_added", function(data){
    console.log("You are here to see ",data.val());
}), function (error) {
    console.log("Error: " + error.code);
});
```

**EDIT 2 -- Updated** -- Adding index for your db

I came across the following SO answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/27878176/3272438

You could try to add the following index rule to index by chatid

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Messages": {
      "chattingid": {
         ".indexOn": ["chatid"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Checkout the following tutorial to get you in the right direction in terms of how to process the data that's returned - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/firebase/firebase_event_types.htm

**EDIT 3**

Because the above EDIT 2 was giving you `Array [ "node_", "ref_", "index_", ]` to the console, that code clearly didn't address the issue.

I utilized some of the examples I came across in [React, Firebase: Access values of JSON and also get key value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51128127/react-firebase-access-values-of-json-and-also-get-key-value/51128154) and the changes I made along with @raphael's answer of looping over the returned object (which is likely an array) to come up with the following piece of code.

Try the following:

```
firebase.database().ref("Messages/" + suid).orderByChild("chattingid/chatid").on("child_added", data => {
            data.forEach(snapshot => {
                console.log("just the val " , snapshot.val());
                console.log("val.chatid " , snapshot.val().chatid);
                console.log("val.chattingid.chatid " , snapshot.val().chattingid.chatid);
            })
 })
```

Comment: I am now getting all-data(as shown in image in my question) in my console. I want to get all chatid's only.

Comment: You're getting all data because that's what you're requesting `firebase.database().ref("Messages/"+suid)`. The only thing `orderByChild("chattingid/chatid")` is doing is sorting the list for you.  If you want to get only the chat ids then my guess is you should iterate over the returned data similar to how @raphael did.  I would start by doing `data.forEach(snapshot => { console.log('snapshot', snapshot) })`

Comment: I have tried raphael's solution, and getting index error. Can you guide me how to index it in firebase realtime db rules. Thanks

Comment: I updated my answer with a potential solution for displaying the keys based on the data returned. This would be a client side solution. I'd have to re-learn some of the firebase db rules in order to help on that side... though I can't do that at the moment. Let me know if that gets you any further.

Comment: @user999 I updated my answer with a potential indexing rule you could try to use

Comment: My console displaying: You are here to see  Array [
  "node_",
  "ref_",
  "index_",
]

Comment: What's displayed when you log `console.log(data)`?

Comment: is it possible to get all node inside ( "Messages/"+suid ).

Comment: console.log displaying this :You are here to see Array [ "node_", "ref_", "index_", ]

Comment: What happens when you `console.log(data.val())` and `console.log("You are here to see ", Object.keys(data.val()));`?

Comment: yes bro console.log("You are here to see ", Object.keys(data.val())); is returning in my console this --> : You are here to see Array [ "node_", "ref_", "index_", ]

Comment: What if you try the following code (it's updated in the example above too): `firebase.database().ref("Messages/"+suid).orderByChild("chattingid/chatid").on("child_added", function(data){
        console.log("You are here to see ",data.val());
    }), function (error) {
        console.log("Error: " + error.code);
    });`

Comment: i am getting all data inside "Messages/"+suid.

Comment: Can you print that out?

Comment: Check out this SO post, it might provide some clarity on what you have to do - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51128127/react-firebase-access-values-of-json-and-also-get-key-value/51128154

Comment: Yes on my pc console all data is displaying as it is in my firebase console. I just want to get all chatid.

Comment: @user999 try my latest edit, `edit 3`. This combines my answer with @raphael's answer and utilizes some of the answers that were posted in the other SO post I just linked to.

Comment: Tried edit 3 . Getting index error. Previously i tried to do indexing in my firebase console which you have mentioned in edit 2. Still same error for indexing,which is " No index defined for chattingid/chatid".

Comment: Updated edit 3, try it now and let me know if any of the three console logs prints anything of interest.

Comment: cant print any console.log() which you have mentioned in edit 3. because firebase is giving indexing error. i have updated my rules which you have mentioned in edit 2 to "chattingid/chatid" , still same indexing error.

Comment: Try just using `orderByChild("chatid")`

Comment: Tried: orderByChild("chatid")

Getting on my console : Error: No index defined for chatid

Comment: Try the updated indexing above, I modified it so it gets deep down into the chattingid/chatid. Also, use the modified edit 3, as I addressed the hierarchy that I messed up previously.

Comment: Applied latest update getting Error:  No index defined for chattingid/chatid on my console.

Comment: Please check I have updated my firebase console image in my question. Note: And to put data inside my chat i am using firebase method push() to insert data while to insert data inside chattingid i am using firebase method set(). Thanks

Comment: @user999 can you post the code you're using to push new data in?